# Python Tk Askstring Dialog Window Focus

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, dialog

I have an application with a GUI which ask's a user for input via Tk Askstring like below...

```
a = askstring('ABC', 'Please enter something!')
```

The problem I have when the dialog box is opened if the user clicks out of the dialog box it brings focus to the root GUI and sends the dialog box behind.

This is the GUI setup...

```
# GUI Attributes
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('800x480')
root.resizable(0, 0)
root.config(cursor='none')
root.title('')
root.wm_attributes('-type', 'splash')
```

Is there a way to set the focus for the askstring dialog box so this cannot happen?

Comment: Provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as I cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: I have added the root setup, this is running on a Raspberry Pi

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
`root.lift()`
If you want the window to stay above all other windows, use:
`root.attributes("-topmost", True)`
Where root is your Toplevel or Tk.

Comment: Thanks for this, I tried this and it makes the main window have focus and stops the dialog box from appearing (goes behind the main window). When I tried this on my Mac this way works fine, it must be OS dependent as this is running on Linux (raspberry pi)